# My attempt at designing a voltage regulator - will this work?

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, voltage-regulator, battery-charging, design

I am recently getting into electronics design and learning about all this fascinating stuff.

I wanted to challenge myself to build a voltage regulator that can take the output from a series of solar panels (18-28V) and regulate it so I can charge a lead acid or NiMH battery (in essence using the circuit as a voltage source).

I wanted to know - would this circuit work? I recently learnt about opamps, they are cheap and hectic so I thought it would a great opportunity to use them in a circuit.

I wanted to avoid using a regulator chip, but I cannot think of a way to do so which would not require more components. Components = moar soldering time.

[image: Circuit design]

Thanks!!!!

Comment: You can use a shunt regulator instead of the 7815 if you want to go even simpler.  Otherwise, it's worth a shot.  Might oscillate though.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why? What Wattage & voltage panel ? What Voltage and Ah battery. As shown the MOSFET will dissipate any panel energy not sent to the battery. Dissipation can be large depending on specifics

Comment: What am I trying to achieve? to learn, and build something useful in the process. In this case I want to regulate a 1.5W cheap ebay solar panel (18V) to the voltage required to charge a battery. The battery will be less than 1Ah (if I use a couple of AA NiMH in series). The battery will be connected directly to a load (probably an arduino).

The only losses I was expecting with the MOSFET was switching losses?

Comment: "Ripple regulator"? I think you want to say "Voltage regulator". Also, solar panels should not have any ripple. Also, you can replace your 7815 with a zener diode/shunt regulator.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're going from ~18 volts to ~ 4 volts, this should more or less work as a voltage regulator. In this role,

1) Change C2 to 0.1 uF - the LM7815 specifies operation at this output capacitance, and 200 uF may well cause it to oscillate. Better yet, try just the LM1815 with the 200 uF cap (not the rest of the circuit) and see what happens. I presume you don't have a scope to look at the circuit, but at a minimum get a cheap DMM. Just be aware that any voltage you see that is not rock-steady is probably undergoing high-frequency weirdness that you can't see directly with a meter. Plus, if you do see what appears to be random drift, quickly touch the part. If you burn your fingertip, you know you need to turn off the power.

2) You don't say what the resistance of the pot is. Don't use 100 ohms.

3) Most important, get rid of C3. That large capacitor will almost certainly cause the output to oscillate.

4) A heatsink on the MOSFET is a very good idea. In theory, you can dissipate more than a watt in it, so you need a decent heat sink.

5) If you decide to do the prudent thing and actually test this circuit before you hook up to a battery, make sure you put a resistor (like, 10 to 100 ohms @ 1 watt) across the output.

With all that said, you need to rethink what you're doing. Recharging a NIMH cell with constant voltage is almost guaranteed to fail. Either the voltage will be too low, and you get no charge, or the voltage will be too high, and you kill the cell. Do some more research.